# Word jumping in iTerm2 or Terminal in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, keymapping

I recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion and Xcode 4.1, and word jumping stopped working in both Terminal and iTerm2. Did the mappings change?

This is with *and* without a homebrew installation of `readline`.

My `.inputrc` looks like this:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify "stopped working": when I press `Ctrl+[left]` or `Ctrl+[right]`, nothing happens. `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+E` still work for line jumping.

Comment: Ctrl+[left|right] for me switch between spaces and full-screen apps. Not sure if that's the default or not. Do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: That's probably it. You can turn them off in Keyboard Shortcuts in System Preferences. Select the "Mission Control" category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mission control took over the same commands as word jumping. thanks to rob cowrie and nicholas riley for the heads-up on that.

Answer (score 152):

Just add the escape sequences in iTerm settings as global shortcut keys.

Word backward (option-arrowleft):

[image: a iTerm settings]

Same with word forward, just use `F`.

Comment: Here's a more detailed description of Nik's method: https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda  I think it's better to use Option than Control for word skipping so iTerm is consistent with every other OSX app.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere which describes more of these esoteric escape sequences and hex codes?

Comment: Not sure, Jonathan. I think these control codes are special to iTerm.

Comment: Make sure, they are not overridden by Profile keys. Also it should be f and not F, b and not B

Comment: @Nitin - F and B works just fine here, but whatever works for you :)

Comment: For some weird reason this doesn't work on Sierra and iTerm2. What could be the problem?

Comment: You definitely (though this may depend on your OS/iTerm version, keyboard layout) do not want to turn the alt/opt keys into escape characters as suggested by the coderwall article. It'll prevent you from using these keys to access special chars. I.e. on a FIN keyboard you couldn't type some quite essential chars like: `|{}[]$`. It also seems to be totally unnecessary as simply modifying the key shortcuts seems to be enough. So please don't read the coderwall artcile, it'll only confuse you. Just set the key combo to send escape sequence b/f.

Comment: thank you! iterm2 high sierra m1 works perfectly!

Answer (score 26):

The easiest/quickest way I have found is under Profiles > Keys > 'Load Preset...' > 'Natural Text Editing'.

Then use the `option` key rather than the `control` key.

(iterm2 version 3)

Answer (score 20):

Killing a fly with a cannon:

- Go to **Preferences...** > **Profiles** > **Keys**
- Press **Load Preset...**
- Select **Natural Text Editing**

Then, you can move a word backwards using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and a word forwards using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>, move to the start of the line using <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and to the end of the line with <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>. Also you can delete a word backwards using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>, delete the whole line using <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>.

If the preset doesn't appear, reinstall iTerm2. If you installed it using Homebrew+Cask:

```
brew cask reinstall iterm2
```

source and credits https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293988/330806

Answer (score 5):

I added the following in my /etc/inputrc

```
# word jump on SHIFT left/right arrows
"\e[1;2D": backward-word
"\e[1;2C": forward-word
```

it works great

Comment: What does the quoted string mean, please?

Comment: they are the escape code generated when you press the arrow keys

Comment: I mean what meaning do they represent for?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/269464/understanding-control-characters-in-inputrc

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps listed in the above answers, I found that on my laptop the first bash (1.bash) will not be able to jump words by pressing option + arrow. Instead, it will simply type in "[D","[C". However, if I create a new bash window (2. bash), the word jump works.